# Linux server's memory not release when upload lots of document files in liferay

Tags: linux, memory, upload, liferay

I had a lot of users upload files and I find the memory not released after user uploaded files. Thus I stop the liferay tomcat, and there is no other applications, while the memory usage still high. So who cost the memory, I guess its linux server cached the documents. Can I get some idea or suggestion from you? I want to release the memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Java has allocated memory from the OS, it'll not free it up again. This is not a feature of Liferay, but of the underlying JVM.

You can allocate less memory to Liferay (or the appserver) to begin with, but must be sure to at least allocate enough for the upload to be processed (AFAIK the documents aren't necessarily held in memory at the same time). You can also configure the cache sizes, so that Liferay won't need to allocate more memory from the OS, at the price of more cache misses. I'm aware of several installations that rather accepted the (minor) impact of cache misses than increasing the overall memory requirements.

However, as memory is so cheap these days, many opt to not optimize this particular aspect. If you can't upgrade your hardware it might be called for though.